# Can you inspect a webapp's filesystem from the chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a website that is using HTML5's Filesystem API to write some files to a temporary file system. Is there any way I can use the Chrome Developer tools to inspect the files I have written?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you go to `chrome://flags` and enable "Enable Developer Tools experiments", then go to the Experiments tab in the Dev Tools settings, there's one named "FileSystem Inspection" that might work. I haven't tried it, though.

**Update:** It seems like this was removed in ~2016 based on the comments here, so this answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: The Experiments tab of the Dev Tools Settings no longer contains a "FileSystem Inspection" item.  I haven't found another way to enable this functionality.

Comment: @super_aardvark I don't even *see* an "Experiments" tab.

Comment: This flag does not exist in Chrome v118.0.5993.70 (2023).

Answer (score 9):

Filesystem inspection [is no longer available](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/kuD9RH1kQe8/0hCD26JQCwAJ).
I couldn't find an official announcement, but it looks this filesystem API is going to be soon deprecated by Chrome as [it was never accepted](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html) as a standard by W3C and nowadays (Jan 2017 with v.55) Google Chrome is the only web browser using it.

Comment: Then *how* do I view all the huge files some web sites have put in my File system to figure out which ones are safe to delete??!?!?!?!

Comment: It is not an official spec, but it is in both Chrome and Firefox. From Mozilla (2021-2022) -- "an attempt was made to create a spec offering the features of Google's API which consensus could be reached on. The result was the File and Directory Entries API. This subset of the API provided by Chrome is still not fully specified; however, for web compatibility reasons, it was decided to implement a subset of the API in Firefox; this was introduced in Firefox 50." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Firefox_support

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, there does not seem to be a built-in way to view the files in the Chrome developer tools as of v106 (2022), perhaps because the file system API was never standardized.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Firefox_support) (2021-2022):

> Work to standardize the specification was abandoned back in 2012, but by that point, Google Chrome included its own implementation of the API. ... an attempt was made to create a spec offering the features of Google's API which consensus could be reached on. The result was the File and Directory Entries API. This subset of the API provided by Chrome is still not fully specified...

**However**, since we have the *console* in the developer tools, we can always get access to the files with some code. Below are some helpful functions, and a tree object of all the files found will be printed in the console where it can be drilled-down into with a few clicks.

```js
/** Get the contents (aka. entries, children) of a directory */
function getEntries(directoryEntry) {
    if (!directoryEntry) return Promise.reject(Error('No directoryEntry param provided'));
    // The entry could be a file (FileEntry, no createReader)
    if (!directoryEntry.createReader) return Promise.resolve([]);
    const directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // The FileError details are not helpful, so let's expand on them
        const handleError = (error) => {
            const vfsError = new Error(
                'Failed to get entries from directory'
                + JSON.stringify(directoryEntry)
                + `due to error ${JSON.stringify(error)}`,
            );
            vfsError.details = { arguments: { directoryEntry }, error };
            reject(vfsError);
        };
        directoryReader.readEntries((entries) => resolve(entries), handleError);
    });
}

/** Get a tree object that contains a name, contents (recursive), and the original entry */
async function getEntriesTree(directoryEntry) {
    const childrenEntries = await getEntries(directoryEntry);
    const contents = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < childrenEntries.length; i += 1) {
        const entry = childrenEntries[i];
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        contents[entry.name] = await getEntriesTree(entry);
    }
    const { name } = directoryEntry;
    return { name, contents, entry: directoryEntry };
}

/** Get the file system (async) */
function getFileSystem() {
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem
    const requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    const type = window.PERSISTENT; // or window.TEMPORARY
    const size = 0; // size of zero requests as much space as possible
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => requestFileSystem(type, size, resolve, reject));
}

// Make the tree object from the file system
(async () => {
    const fileSystem = await getFileSystem();
    const tree = await getEntriesTree(fileSystem.root);
    console.log('file system tree:', tree);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It cost me long time to search the inspector, as other people shows in their blog . I am using v.63, it's no longer exists .

but their is another method to do it with web terminal . maybe you can do like this http://www.htmlfivewow.com/demos/terminal/terminal.html