# edit txt file with javascript or html5

Tags: javascript, html, file, text-files

Please I need help to edit a txt file in client side, I can't find a good method. I need update the data automatic, without confirmation, like it:

```
 <button onclick="updatefile()">Update</button>
   <script>
      functiom updatefile(){
         var file = "d:\test.txt"          
         var data = //here any function for load all data from file
         ...
         ...
         data .= " new data to add";

         //here any function for save data in test.txt  
         .....
      }
</script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can read a local file using the [File Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), but there is no way to automatically save back to a file from a browser (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in that manner using JS. What you CAN do though is to download it on the client, without having the server intervene by using `data urls`.

Setting the name of said downloaded file is not cross browser compatible unfortunately...

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type something here and click save"></textarea>
<br>
<a id="save" href="">Save</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
// This defines the data type of our data. application/octet-stream
// makes the browser download the data. Other properties can be added
// while separated by semicolons. After the coma (,) follows the data
var prefix = 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,';
$('#text').on('keyup', function(){
  if($(this).val()){
    // Set the URL by appending the base64 form of your text. Keep newlines in mind
    $('#save').attr('href', prefix + btoa($(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '\r\n')));
    // For browsers that support it, you can even set the filename of the 
    // generated 'download'
    $('#save').attr('download', 'text.txt');
  }else{
    $('#save').removeAttr('href');
    $('#save').removeAttr('download');
  }
});
```

Comment: is possible select a custom directory for save the file?, or always the file is stored in google chrome directory

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this. It's up to the browser. If your app is a web application you can temporary store your text in local storage, but you'll have to go through a download to actually get the file.

Comment: If your application is a packaged app (like a chrome extension or a stand-alone chrome app) you might be able to save files to a sandbox filesystem but I haven't used it personally. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213397/where-is-the-file-sandbox-for-a-chrome-app